# Create json column from multiple rows using pyspark

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I would like to have a column in a pyspark df in json format.

exmaple df:

| id | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 11 |
| 1 | b | 12 |
| 2 | c | 21 |

expected outcome:

| id | json |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"a":"11","b":"12","c":""} |
| 2 | {"a":"","b":"","c":"21"} |

I tried to use

```
df.groupBy(df.id) \
    .agg(collect_list(to_json(create_map(df.type, df.value))).alias('json')) \
```

but it returns a nested json like this `{{"a":"11"},{"b":"12"}}`

can someone help me with this, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

exemple df:

```
df  = spark.createDataFrame(
      [
        ('1','a','11'),
        ('1','b','12'),
        ('2','c','21')
      ], ['id','type','value']
    )
```

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupBy("id")\
    .agg(F.map_from_entries(F.collect_list(F.struct("type", "value"))).alias("type_value"))\
    .withColumn('json', F.to_json('type_value'))\
    .show(truncate=False)

+---+------------------+-------------------+
|id |type_value        |json               |
+---+------------------+-------------------+
|1  |{a -> 11, b -> 12}|{"a":"11","b":"12"}|
|2  |{c -> 21}         |{"c":"21"}         |
+---+------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! although is it possible to have the empty value in the json too? when the `type` is restricted to a, b, and c

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to do this. See below logic -

**Input_DF**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([StructField("id", StringType(), True), StructField("type", StringType(), True), StructField("value", StringType(), True)])

df  = spark.createDataFrame([('1','a','11'),('1','b','12'),('2','c','21')], schema)
df.show(truncate=False)

+---+----+-----+
| id|type|value|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|   a|   11|
|  1|   b|   12|
|  2|   c|   21|
+---+----+-----+
```

First, pivot the `type` column and aggregate it using its corresponding `value` as below -

```
df1 = df.groupBy("id").pivot("type").agg(first("value"))
df1.show()

+---+----+----+----+
| id|   a|   b|   c|
+---+----+----+----+
|  1|  11|  12|null|
|  2|null|null|  21|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Once you have this, you have to replace `null` values to its `string` equivalent. Having said that, spark ignores `null` values while creating `json` column from `struct` type. See below -

```
df1.select(*(df1.columns)).fillna("null").withColumn("json", regexp_replace(to_json(struct(col("a"), col("b"), col("c"))), "null", "")).drop("a", "b", "c").show(truncate=False)

+---+--------------------------+
|id |json                      |
+---+--------------------------+
|1  |{"a":"11","b":"12","c":""}|
|2  |{"a":"","b":"","c":"21"}  |
+---+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df  = spark.createDataFrame(
      [
        ('1','a','11'),
        ('1','b','12'),
        ('2','c','21')
      ], ['id','type','value']
    )

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def input_type(json):
    dic_json = eval(json)
    for x in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
       if x not in dic_json: dic_json[x] = ''
    return dic_json

input_type_udf = F.udf(input_type, StringType())

df.groupBy("id")\
    .agg(F.map_from_entries(F.collect_list(F.struct("type", "value"))).alias("type_value"))\
    .withColumn('json', F.to_json('type_value'))\
    .withColumn('dic_json', input_type_udf(F.col('json')))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

```
+---+------------------+-------------------+----------------+
|id |type_value        |json               |dic_json        |
+---+------------------+-------------------+----------------+
|1  |{a -> 11, b -> 12}|{"a":"11","b":"12"}|{a=11, b=12, c=}|
|2  |{c -> 21}         |{"c":"21"}         |{a=, b=, c=21}  |
+---+------------------+-------------------+----------------+
```